# Post to Create Action Using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to post to my registration controller using a link_to link.

I have `<%= link_to "Register for Period", registration_path(period_id: period.id), :method => :post %>`

Which generates a link like: `http://localhost:3000/registrations/6?period_id=25` where the 6 is the event_id. I need to save the period_id and the user_id to the registration database.

I get the following error in the browser: `No route matches [POST] "/registrations/6"`

What am I doing wrong?

routes:

```
Mavens::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :events
  resources :periods
  resources :products
  resources :cart_rows
  resources :product_requests
  resources :inqueries
  resources :registrations
   match '/profile',  to: 'static_pages#profile'

  root :to => 'static_pages#home'

  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/about"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :registrations do
  member do
    post :save_period
  end
end
```

And in your link:

```
<%= link_to "Register for period", 
  save_period_registration_path(id: @registration.id, period_id: period.id), :method => :post %>
```

You will have a route that matches your resquest.
When you only have a `resources :registrations` rule on your `routes.rb`, only the default restful routes are created, and there is no `POST` to a single resource created by default.
I believe you will have to read something about the CSRF token, because if you have a `protect_from_forgery` on your `application_controller`, probably this `POST` request from a single link would not work.

Comment: I get `can't use member outside resource(s) scope`. I am in my events controller, which I think is causing the issue.

Comment: So you are saying that the link should make a request to the events_controller?

Comment: No, it should make request to the registrations controller's create action.

Comment: But, I think you're missing a do after :registrations.

Comment: if I add the do in, I get: `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

Comment: Ah yes, a little typo in there. Lemme edit the post again, and you try it. I added the `id:` hash key too.

Comment: Now it is time for you to check your params hash and see if it are passing the right ones to the controller.

Comment: Don't I need to tell the router that save_periods goes to the create controller?

Comment: I am getting the following error: `The action 'save_period' could not be found for RegistrationsController` with the correct params hash.

Comment: No no, instead of the `create` method on your controller, rename it to `save_period`.

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes.rb is missing the required path. It IS a standard path, so adding 'resources :registrations' would work.

If more complex, post your routes.rb and we can tell what to add.